# Depends: samba4-common-bin

Tags: 12.10, updates, samba

I have just made the update to the 12.10 version. But when I tried to install all the updates I received the following messages:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

samba4: Depends: samba4-common-bin (= 4.0.0~alpha18.dfsg1-4ubuntu2) but 4.0.0~beta2+dfsg1-3 is installed
        Depends: upstart-job but it is a virtual package

Can someone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify the version 12.12 does not exist.  If your not sure try `lsb_release -a` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command to install dependencies:

`sudo apt-get upgrade -f`

Comment: It works ty very much

Comment: No problem, glad I can help.